# Text to CSV in nested lists for multiple delimiters (skipping first occurrence)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

My data looks like this

```
[['15/09/16, 12:21 pm - User1: Hey'],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: <Media omitted>'],
 ["15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: It's yesterday's work"],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User1: Gotta work on it.']]
```

I am trying to separate this nested list into each column of Date, Time, UserName, Message.

Now my delimiters are

`,`  to separate date,

`-` to separate Time,

`:` to separate UserName and Message

But the problem is if I use `:`, it will split the Time as well since that is in format of `XX:XX`.

As of now, my first step is to get the split properly and then I can move forward with converting to csv.

**Attempt 1 -**
I tried to split the data directly while reading but nothing changed.

```
delim=",","-",":"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delim))
data = []
for line in open('/content/drive/My Drive/sample.txt'):
    items = line.rstrip('\r\n').split(regexPattern)   # strip new-line characters and split on column delimiter
    items = [item.strip() for item in items]  # strip extra whitespace off data items
    data.append(items)
```

**Attempt 2 -** 
I tried to split while writing into csv

```
delim=",","-",":"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delim))
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    re.split(regexPattern,data)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

This runs into error because split expects a string and I have a list. Not sure how to achieve my main goal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hi @PirateX do you have case where users have `-` or `,` or `;` at any other place apart from this expected places.

Comment: Judging from his comment on Rakesh's answer, he does.

Comment: Yes, the message column may or may not have any of the delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern `re.compile(r",|\-|\:\s+")`

**Ex:**

```
import re
data = [['15/09/16, 12:21 pm - User1: Hey'],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: <Media omitted>'],
 ["15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: It's yesterday's work"],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User1: Gotta work on it.']]


regexPattern = re.compile(r",|\-|\:\s+")
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        print(regexPattern.split(j))
```

**Output:**

```
['15/09/16', ' 12:21 pm ', ' User1', 'Hey']
['15/09/16', ' 12:22 pm ', ' User2', '<Media omitted>']
['15/09/16', ' 12:22 pm ', ' User2', "It's yesterday's work"]
['15/09/16', ' 12:22 pm ', ' User1', 'Gotta work on it.']
```

---

Using Regex grouping.

**Demo:**

```
import re
data = [['15/09/16, 12:21 pm - User1: Hey'],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: <Media omitted>'],
 ["15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: It's yesterday's work"],
 ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User1: Gotta work on it, what,hello.']]


regexPattern = re.compile(r"(?P<date>\d{2,}\/\d{2,}\/\d{2,}),\s*(?P<time>\d{2,}:\d{2,}\s*[a-z]{2,})\s*\-\s*(?P<user>\w+)\:\s*(?P<msg>.*)$")
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        print(regexPattern.match(j).groups())
```

**Output:**

```
('15/09/16', '12:21 pm', 'User1', 'Hey')
('15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User2', '<Media omitted>')
('15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User2', "It's yesterday's work")
('15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User1', 'Gotta work on it, what,hello.')
```

Comment: this works well but it splits again if it encounters ',' again in Message column. I want it to skip splitting in messages column

Comment: I used maxsplit = 3 for my use case. I think that should work out.

Answer (score 2):

without RegEx

```
def parse(item):
    date_time, user_message =  item.split(' - ', 1)
    return [*date_time.split(', '), *user_message.split(': ', 1)]

eggs = [['15/09/16, 12:21 pm - User1: Hey'],
        ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: <Media omitted>'],
        ["15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User2: It's yesterday's work"],
        ['15/09/16, 12:22 pm - User1: Gotta work on it.']]

spam = [parse(egg[0]) for egg in eggs]
print(spam)
```

output

```
[['15/09/16', '12:21 pm', 'User1', 'Hey'],
 ['15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User2', '<Media omitted>'],
 ['15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User2', "It's yesterday's work"],
 ['15/09/16', '12:22 pm', 'User1', 'Gotta work on it.']]
```

- formatting of the output is from me for clarity
- you need to explicitly specify maxsplit to be 1

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfect case for using regex groups.

```
s = '15/09/16, 12:21 pm - User1: Hey'
ms = re.match(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+).+?(\d+:\d+).+-\s(.*):\s(.*)', s)

print(ms.groups()) # ('15/09/16', '12:21', 'User1', 'Hey')
```

You can rejoin them to csv line.

Comment: The time should be `12:21` and the User is skipped too

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Oops typo in regex, fixed.